# Spring Application doesn't see internal files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

So I'm new to Spring and found difficult to access html files through controller. Project build on Maven. Here is project structure: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQZUk.png)
I'd configured my file by such classes:

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("eng.springmvc")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class FirstController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloPage() {
        return "first/hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/goodbye")
    public String goodByePage() {
        return "first/goodbye";
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what's the reason I'm accessing 404 not found page instead of hello page?

I've tried to view few posts on stack overflow and rebuild my project from 0. Have no idea why it's not working:(